# How can I get best selling products of last month on a shopify store in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I am looking for a way to get best selling products of last month on a shopify store in `javascript`. I know how to get best selling products of all time. Please see the code below.

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://www.exampleshopifysite.com/collections/all/products.json?sort-by=best-selling",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache"

  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: There is no way, rather than using Shopify APIs.

Answer (score 0):

The url you've provided doesn't seem to provide relevant information.

But you can extract below information.

`id,title,handle,body_html,published_at,created_at,updated_at,vendor,product_type,tags,variants,images,options`

Example script ([link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5sxqrd7/1/))

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://spritude.com/collections/all/products.json?sort-by=best-selling",
  "method": "GET",
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  response.products.slice(0, 10).forEach(product => {
    console.log(`ID: ${product.id}`);
    console.log(`TITLE: ${product.title}`);
    console.log(`HANDLE: ${product.handle}`);
    console.log(`PUBLISHED AT: ${product.published_at}`);
    console.log(`CREATED AT: ${product.created_at}`);
    console.log(`UPDATED AT: ${product.updated_at}`);
    console.log(`VENDOR: ${product.vendor}`);
    console.log(`PRODUCT TYPE: ${product.product_type}`);
    console.log(`TAGS: ${product.tags}`);
  });
});
```

Comment: The url is an example url. It is irrelevant. The main point in the question was **last month**. I want to know how I can get best selling products of the **last month** in javascript. Your answer does not seem to address the main point.

Comment: i dont mean the relevancy of url, but the url structure - `hostname/collections/all/products.json?sort-by=best-selling`. this url provides only publish, creation and modification timestamps. none of them i guess is suitable for your query. 
i'm afraid you might need aggregate of orders/sales of last month with products.

Comment: How to programmatically access sales data of a product in javascript on a store I am not an admin of? If you share an example, I will immediately accept your answer. You may share the url to access json data. I will write code myself.

Comment: you can't go inside a random shop and ask for a commercial secret such as - last month's best selling products. in order to do that you must have a relevant relationship with that shop administration.